# Parameterizing a raw type

Tags: java, generics

I have a `Vector` like so:

```
Vector myVector = new Vector();
```

And an `ArrayList` of a custom class which contains `n` amount of `String`s.

Basically, I add an empty item into the first position in the Vector (`myVector.insertElementAt("", 0);`), and then add (usually) the rest of the items from the `ArrayList` (depending on the needs). This `Vector` then is used as the the `DefaultComboBoxModel` for a `JComboBox`.

Now, I get the usual warning *References to the generic type Vector  should be parameterized*.

The items are of type `String`, but I can't use `Vector<String>` because adding the items from the `ArrayList` (using `.add()`) won't work as:

*The method add(String) in the type Vector(String) is not applicable for the arguments (CustomClass).*

I can't use `Vector(CustomClass)` because then `insertElementAt` throws a wobbler.

So my question is: Is it safe to just use `Vector(Object)` or not parameterize the type at all?

I could use `T` and cast everything but would get a type safety error.

Comment: Could you provide us with some code that shows what you are trying to do and how?

Comment: Are the items in your ArrayList strings or not...? You say they are but the error "is not applicable for the arguments (CustomClass)" implies that they're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use Vector because adding the items from the ArrayList (using .add()) won't work as:
>
> > The method add(String) in the type Vector(String) is not applicable for the arguments (CustomClass).

So, you are trying to add things from an `ArrayList<CustomClass>` to a `Vector` that you expect only to contain `String` elements.

If you are using a raw-typed `Vector`, you can do this, but it will fail down the line if you try to do anything with an element from that `Vector` that you treat as a `String`, because it's not.

If you want the `Vector` to contain `String`s, add a `String`:

```
myVector.add(thingFromArrayList.toString());
```

(or some other means of converting `thingFromArrayList` to a `String`)

and then you can add the `<String>` to `myVector`'s type.

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. I'm (slightly) ashamed I didn't even think of this.

Comment: @notyou we all miss obvious solutions sometimes.